# Where can I get the epoll library for Linux?

Tags: linux, library

yum doesn't seem to have it, and I can't find it on google. Is epoll part of a larger package/library? Where can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The epoll "library" is a set of system calls that should be already available in your kernel (it was introduced in kernel 2.5.44).  If you are getting a specific error in compilation, you should provide it in your question so more specific assistance can be provided.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Looks like epoll wasn't required, and everything built correctly.